# Using python to count string occurrences in a flat file

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete an online course and one question is to count the number of occurrences of the word "fantastic" in a large file. When an occurrence is found the first element of that line needs to be stored (the id) to build up a list of lines(ids) containing the word. So far I have the below which is reading the lines correctly but I can't figure out how to check if "fantastic" is somewhere in that line in upper/lower case. I've tried using `row.count('fantastic')` which didn't work as I'm not sure how csv reader stores the lines, if I can get them counting I can just add the id to array and print it at the end when once or more occurrences are found per line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv

def main():
    f = open("test_file.txt", 'rt')
    filereader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='      ', quotechar='"')
    for row in filereader:
        print row[0]
        print row.count('fantastic')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is a very small sample set where I've thrown in a few fantastic's.

```
"6361"  "When will unit 2 be online? fantastic"   "cs101 unit2"   "100003292"     "<p>When will unit 2 be online?</p>"    "question"      "\N"    "\N"    "2012-02-26 15:47:12.522262+00" "0"     "(closed)"      "51919" "100003292"     "2012-03-03 10:12:27.41521+00"  "21196" "\N"    "\N"    "186"   "t"
"7185"  "Hungarian group"       "cs101 hungarian nationalities" "100003268"     "<p>Hi there! This is FANTASTIC</p>
<p>Any Hungarians doing the course? We could form a group!<br>
;)</p>" "question"      "\N"    "\N"    "2012-02-27 15:09:11.184434+00" "0"     ""      "\N"    "100003268"     "2012-02-27 15:09:11.184434+00" "9322"  "\N"    "\N"    "106"   "f"
"26454" "Course Application."   "cs101 application."    "100003192"     "<p>Please tell about the Course Application.  How to use the Course for higher education and jobs?</p>" "question"      "\N"    "\N"    "2012-03-08 08:34:06.704674+00" "-1"    ""      "\N"    "100003192"     "2012-03-08 08:34:06.704674+00" "34477" "\N"    "\N"    "73"    "f"
```

I would expect the output to be 6361, 7185

Comment: Are you sure that's not a tab delimited file?

Comment: Your question says "flat file" yet you read the file with csv reader. Which is correct? From the sample, I would assume csv, but it's better if we can be sure.

Comment: In any case, `row.count(xxxxx)` would count the number of occurences of item xxxxx in the list. That is here: occurences of the exact string "fantastic". With nothing before or after it.

Comment: Sorry it's a tab delimited file, but it's being read fine by CSV reader as far as I can tell. Ah okay, I guess that's why it's not finding the occurrences of the string inside other text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default quote character is already `"` so you don't need to specify that, but if you've got a tab delimited file, passing in `'\t'` as the delimiter will correctly interpret the columns.

What you can do is build a generator to filter rows based on whether the substring `'fantastic'` appears in any columns after the ID, then use a list comprehension to extract the IDs, eg:

```
with open('test_file.txt') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    has_fantastic = (row for row in csvin if any('fantastic' in col.lower() for col in row[1:]))
    ids = [row[0] for row in has_fantastic]
```

Comment: I always seem to get an error using "with open" so that's why I've been using just open. Error message: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with the arrow pointing to "open". Maybe as I'm using quite an old version on this system (2.4.3) ?

Comment: @MattDamon Yup - the `with` statement became default in Python 2.6+ and was available as a future import in 2.5... You should really consider changing your Python version to something not 11 years old :)

Comment: "Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 14 2011, 00:20:04)" Is it not from 2011 then? ha, it's on a work server and we don't use python at all so that's why it's not updated. I'll fire it up on a virtual machine instead.

Comment: @Matt that's the *build date* - Python 2.4 was released in November 2004 - if you're going to upgrade Python - either use the latest 2.7 release if you need to stick with the 2.x series or preferably go with at least 3.4

Comment: Both good answers but yours was slightly shorter. Used map to convert the list to integers and then sort to sort them afterwards. Managed to get a newer version on a VM :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

First, make sure that those are not tabs rather than spaces.

Second, if you use csv, the result is a list for each row. You need to check each string in the list. You can either use `any` or `join` to make a single string.

Third, you need to use `lower()` since 'FANTASTIC' is not the same as 'fantastic'

```
import csv

def main():
    f = open("test_file.txt", 'rt')
    filereader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in filereader:
        if any('fantastic' in e.lower() for e in row[1:]):
            print row[0]
```

To gather all the rows into a list, you might do something like:

```
def main():
    result=[]
    with open("/tmp/so.csv", 'rt') as f:
        filereader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
        for row in filereader:
            if any('fantastic' in e.lower() for e in row[1:]):
                result.append(row[0])
    print result
```

Comment: I get a "NameError: global name 'any' is not defined" using the first approach and a syntax error when using "with open" which I mentioned in an above comment. I'm not sure if this is to do with my python version (2.4.3)?